# Openstack python api: How create a connection using Application Credentials?

Tags: python, openstack, keystone, openstack-python-api

Currently I am using (of course with more elaborate variables):

```
conn = openstack.connect(
                load_yaml_config=False,
                load_envvars=False,
                auth_url=AL,
                project_name=PN,
                username=UN,
                password=PW,
                region_name=RN,
                user_domain_name=UDN,
                project_domain_name=PDN,
                app_name=42,
                app_version=42
            )
```

to connect to projects. But in the future I would like to offer using application credentials, too. While there is plenty of documentation on how to authenticate with said credentials, I can't find anything about authenticating a connection with it. **How is it done?**

So what I am looking for is a way to create a connection without username and password, but credentials instead.

- On connection: https://docs.openstack.org/openstacksdk/latest/user/connection.html
- On application credentials: https://docs.openstack.org/keystone/queens/user/application_credentials.html
- On rest-api calls https://docs.openstack.org/api-ref/identity/v3/index.html#application-credentials

**Existing authenticated session**

This might be an option:

```
From existing authenticated Session
-----------------------------------

For applications that already have an authenticated Session, simply passing
it to the :class:`~openstack.connection.Connection` constructor is all that
is needed:

.. code-block:: python

    from openstack import connection

    conn = connection.Connection(
        session=session,
        region_name='example-region',
        compute_api_version='2',
        identity_interface='internal')
```

but I have to investigate further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find any documentation, but apparently it is possible to create a connection like this:

```
    openstack.connect(
        load_yaml_config=False,
        load_envvars=False,
        auth_url=AU,
        region_name=RN,
        application_credential_id=ACI,
        application_credential_secret=ACS,
        auth_type=AT
    )
```

and that will return a connection object just like before. `auth_type` has to be `"v3applicationcredential"` when using application credentials.

Comment: I was looking for the exact same thing, so thank you !

Comment: Was that really working for you @Natan? It doesn't for me (`TypeError: BaseGenericPlugin.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'auth_type'`) and I cannot find any reference to `application_credential_secret` in the sources https://opendev.org/openstack/openstacksdk/search?q=application_credential_secret either. However, I have to admit that I am somewhat confused by the history/evolution of the OpenStack APIs and what's now the official client or not. What's the PyPI package?

Comment: The current version we use is a bit more elaborated than the one above due to the fact that it supports application credentials and passwords. However, the above works. Currently we use `openstacksdk==0.62` and `python-openstackclient==6.0.0`, but that is not because of the connection, but a deprecation warning that does more than just warn. OpenStacks documentation can be hell. Maybe open up your problem as a question and drop a link and I will take a look if I can figure out what's going wrong.

Comment: Thank you very much. After your confirmation, I noticed that I was using a slightly different way how to construct a connection, using the `auth` argument, assuming naively it would lead to the same result (it doesn't). Following your API call (argument for argument) worked. When browsing the source, I now assume the reason I didn't find application credential arguments in the sources is that Keystone is resolving them (they are handed in opaquely as it seems).

Thank you very much!

Comment: P.S.: The versioning scheme was also a bit surprising. https://pypi.org/project/openstacksdk/#history shows that your version 0.62 was newer than any other 0.x versions with a higher number. Somewhat strange.